# Retrieving multiple JSON objects from a JSON array within another JSON array?

Tags: java, android, json

For a college assignment I need to create an app that retrieves product data from the API of a well known Dutch online store. I need to store the title, summary, price and image URLs of each product into a new Product object. These Products are stored into an ArrayList and the ArrayList is then returned.

Each product within the products array has a nested array called "images", which contains 6 product images. These images need to stored into my Product object's HashMap attribute, with the image size as key and the URL as value. However, I can't seem to get it right.

JSON data with the query "pokemon": https://api.bol.com/catalog/v4/search/?apikey=25C4742A92BF468EB2BD888FC8FBFF40&format=json&q=pokemon

Product class:

```java
package com.example.bolcombrowser.domain;

import java.util.Map;

public class Product {

    // Attributes
    private String mTitle;
    private String mSummary;
    private double mPrice;
    private Map < String, String > mImageUrls;

    // Constructor
    public Product(String mTitle, String mSummary, double mPrice, Map < String, String > mImageUrls) {
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
        this.mSummary = mSummary;
        this.mPrice = mPrice;
        this.mImageUrls = mImageUrls;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    public String getmTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
    }

    public String getmSummary() {
        return mSummary;
    }

    public void setmSummary(String mSummary) {
        this.mSummary = mSummary;
    }

    public double getmPrice() {
        return mPrice;
    }

    public void setmPrice(double mPrice) {
        this.mPrice = mPrice;
    }

    public Map < String, String > getImageUrls() {
        return mImageUrls;
    }

    public void setImageUrls(Map < String, String > imageUrls) {
        this.mImageUrls = imageUrls;
    }
}
```

parseJson method:

```java
public static ArrayList < Product > parseJson(String productJsonStr) throws JSONException {

    /* JSON array names. */
    final String BOL_PRODUCTS = "products";
    final String BOL_IMAGES = "images";
    final String BOL_OFFERS = "offers";

    /* JSON key names. */
    final String BOL_TITLE = "title";
    final String BOL_SUMMARY = "summary";
    final String BOL_OFFERDATA = "offerData";
    final String BOL_PRICE = "price";
    final String BOL_KEY = "key";
    final String BOL_URL = "url";

    /* Variables to store product data into, and is then used to create new Product objects. */
    String title;
    String summary;
    double price;
    Map < String, String > imageUrls = new HashMap < > ();

    /* ArrayList to store products into. */
    ArrayList < Product > productList = new ArrayList < > ();

    JSONObject productsJson = new JSONObject(productJsonStr);

    JSONArray productsArray = productsJson.getJSONArray(BOL_PRODUCTS);

    for (int i = 0; i < productsArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject product = productsArray.getJSONObject(i);

        /* Retrieve the title and summary of each product. */
        title = product.getString(BOL_TITLE);
        summary = product.getString(BOL_SUMMARY);

        JSONArray imagesArray = product.getJSONArray(BOL_IMAGES);

        for (int j = 0; j < imagesArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject image = imagesArray.getJSONObject(j);

            /* Retrieve each product's image sizes and URLs and store them into a HashMap. */
            String imageSize = image.getString(BOL_KEY);
            String imageUrl = image.getString(BOL_URL);

            imageUrls.put(imageSize, imageUrl);
        }

        JSONObject offerData = product.getJSONObject(BOL_OFFERDATA);
        JSONArray offers = offerData.getJSONArray(BOL_OFFERS);
        JSONObject offer = offers.getJSONObject(0);
        price = offer.getDouble(BOL_PRICE);

        productList.add(new Product(title, summary, price, imageUrls));
    }

    return productList;
}
```

onPostExecute method:

```java
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String productData) {
    if (productData != null) {
        ArrayList < Product > productList;

        try {
            productList = JsonUtils.parseJson(productData);

            for (Product product: productList) {
                String title = product.getmTitle();
                String summary = product.getmSummary();
                double price = product.getmPrice();
                String hashMap = product.getImageUrls().toString();

                mTextViewOutput.append(title + "\n\n" + summary + "\n\n" + price + "\n\n" +
                    hashMap + "\n\n\n\n\n");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I test out my app, it seems to have stored the image URLs of the last product into every product's HashMap:

[image]

I've been staring at my code for hours and I can't seem to find out why it does this. I'm probably making a very silly mistake but I just can't seem to figure out what it is exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Map<String, String> imageUrls = new HashMap<>();` is in the wrong place. It should be inside your first for loop, otherwise you are using the same `Map` for all your products.

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < productsArray.length(); i++) {
    Map<String, String> imageUrls = new HashMap<>();
...
```

By the way, I suggest using [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library. It will make your code less boilerplate

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it. I will definitely look into gson.